# Android Bluetooth Broadcast Receiver Issues with ACL_CONNECTED and AC_DISCONNECTED

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I am writing an app that detects whether or not a bluetooth device is connected. After doing some research I found that the best way to do it was to use a broadcast receiver with some bluetooth related intent filters.

```
<receiver android:name=".BTReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />             
            </intent-filter>  
        </receiver>
```

And here is my bluetooth receiver class.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED") || action.equals("android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED") ){
            Log.d("Z","Received: Bluetooth Connected");
        }
        if(action.equals("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED") ||action.equals("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED_REQUESTED")){
            Log.d("Z","Received: Bluetooth Disconnected");
        }
        Log.d("Z",action);
}
```

When I turn on my bluetooth headset and it connects to my phone, I receive "android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" twice. When I disconnect the bluetooth headset, the broadcast receiver doesn't run or receive anything. So I never receive my Bluetooth Disconnected Log message. I am using the two bluetooth permissions that I thought were necessary to get this to work.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

I could really use any information on what is wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: Is this for bluetooth headset only?

Comment: I was aiming for bluetooth headset and bluetooth through a car.

Comment: Do you put your broadcast receiver in an activity or service?

Comment: No I didn't. It's currently it's own class.

For example: public class BTReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got your action wrong.

```
<receiver android:name=".BTReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />           
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>
```

Remove the

```
|| action.equals("android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED")
```

since CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED could be connected, disconnected etc.. so that your first **if** is always true. You do not need to register for android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED unless you do anything specific with a2dp.

Thus, it should be

```
if(action.equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED") {
        Log.d("Z","Received: Bluetooth Connected");
    }
    if(action.equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED") ||action.equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED")){
        Log.d("Z","Received: Bluetooth Disconnected");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Hoan. I tried your suggestion and neither log is printed when turning my bluetooth headset off and on. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Your edit worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I just had to change the action in the intent-filters and in the onReceive.